# Initializing a variable in a UIView assuming boundaries have been set

Tags: swift, uiview, core-graphics

This is a question of exactly when the `UIView`'s bounds variable is set and initialized. I have a variable `ballSize` in my view that is initialized using the bounds variable of the view as follows:

```
private var ballSize: CGSize {
        let size = bounds.size.width / 20
        return CGSize(width: size, height: size)
}
```

Everything works nicely, as intended. So when exactly is it, that the bounds of the `UIView` are set? And is it always safe to assume that I can use the bounds in the initialization of a variable in the `UIView` class?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UIView programmatically then you will get correct value of bounds after `addSubview` method called or if you are using UIVIew from `Xib` then do your initialization in `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`.

Comment: My question is, is the `UIView` 's bounds set in the initialization before other variables that I define in the `UIView` class, so that I can use it in the initialization of the variables as above?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which initializer you are using. Assuming you are calling your outmost `UIView` using `UIView(CGRect(x,y,width,height))`, then you can safely use the bounds property asap. If you are not passing a frame inside the `init`, then it might not be available yet for your subviews.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like using 'bounds' in the initialization of a variable in a `UIView` class is not allowed, since this is equivalent to 'self.bounds'. In fact, I get a "Cannot use instance member 'bounds' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" error if I try do this:

`private var ballSize = CGSize(width: bounds.size.width/20, height: bounds.size.height/20)`

For some reason, the above code in the question works with the access to 'self.bounds' because the variable is a computed property.